# mailto: struts2

Tags: struts2

I am using struts2 and i have property  and want to make it a 
mailto link.

Can anybody help me how to get it.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming an action such as:

```
class SomeAction {
    private String email;
    // ...
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
}
```

You can access it in the JSP using the following:

Struts 2 Tag: `<s:property value="email"/>`

JSP EL: `${action.email}`

Comment: No, i want a mailto link functionality  something like this
    <a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com?cc=someoneelse@theirsite.com">someone@yoursite.com</a> In my struts2 form i have property  <s:property value="email"/>

Comment: Uhh. `<a href="mailto:${action.email}">${action.email}</a>` ? (You can do the same with the `<s:property/>` tag.)

Comment: thanks a lot. Here is how I wrote    <td class="viewCell"><a href='mailto:<s:property value="accEmail" />'><s:property value="accEmail" /></a></td>

Comment: Glad to hear it. Don't forget to accept this answer if you found it helpful.